# how to delete values that cannot be interpreted as a number in CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large data table. It looks like this,
(example)

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2aiM.png)

I want to drop all the string values from the CSV.

I tried this,

```
df.drop(['document.children.children.id', 'document.id', 'document.name', 'document.type', 'document.children.name', 'document.children.type', 'document.children.children.name', 'document.children.children.type', 'document.children.children.blendMode', 'document.children.children.children.blendMode', 'document.children.children.children.fills.blendMode', 'document.children.children.children.fills.type'], axis=1, inplace=True )
```

But when I try another design this won't work. I want to know how can I drop all string values from CSV? Without using the above method.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a technical nitpick: a CSV is inherently a string, so I think maybe what you're asking is how to delete certain columns or how to delete values that cannot be interpreted as a number.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the data type each column into appropriate data type. Then you can easily drop the columns with a string data type by applying select_dtype method as following:
df_numeric = df.drop(df.select_dtypes("object"), axis = 1)